# Jquery - Unable to show slider on the web-page - Edited?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to web development. I am trying to use jquery to show slider on the web-page. However, I am not able to see the silder on the web-page. I tried debugging the code via. firebug. However, I don't see any error over there. Can somebody please tell me on what I am missing possibly?

I am using Linux - Fedora core 16 and  Firefox- 38.0.5 to run this code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <script src=  "jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
   <script src=  "js/jquery-ui.js">   </script>
   <script src=  "js/jqueryTutorial.js">   </script>

 <title> "My Page"</title>  

 <head> "Hello Jquery"</head>

<body>

<div id="slider"> </div>

</body>   

</html>
```

Here is the jqueryTutorial.js file.

```
(function() {

  $("#slider").slider();

})();
```

There are no errors in the firebug console. 
Here is the screen shot.

[image]

---

Finally, I did the following from the source - jquery slider

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Now, I see the following error on the firebug.

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined


$(function() {


index.html (line 11, col 2)
```

Comment: Is jquery-2.1.4.min.js in your root?

Comment: There are no errors in the firebug console.  Also, the jquery-2.1.4.min.js in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
(function() {

  $("#slider").slider();

})();
});
```

**EDITED:**

Ok , the issue comes from the  tags.

You wrote this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <script src=  "jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
   <script src=  "js/jquery-ui.js">   </script>
   <script src=  "js/jqueryTutorial.js">   </script>

 <title> "My Page"</title>  

 <head> "Hello Jquery"</head>

<body>

<div id="slider"> </div>

</body>   

</html>
```

And you HAVE to write this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script src=  "jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
   <script src=  "js/jquery-ui.js">   </script>
   <script src=  "js/jqueryTutorial.js">   </script>

 <title> "My Page"</title>  


</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"> </div>

</body>   

</html>
```

;-)

**EDITED AGAIN**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  jQuery(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your <head></head> tags

Comment: I have even copied the code from jquery website. it's still not working. You can check my revised question now... check at the below.

Comment: I checked with your code. There are no errors on the console. However, I can't see a slider on the web page - firefox. Am I missing something. Is styling needs to be used to see a slider on the web page?

Comment: Ok, the jquery website example doesn't work because yo have to call the scripts with http.  <script src=" http //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: If with this change works now , be sure that your files in js/ are there and they are the right ones.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get. Can you please elaborate the correct syntax for me?

Comment: I edited my response . Copy the last code and try to execute it from your own html file

Answer (score 0):

Include your `<script>` tags before closing body tag `</body>`. Moreover you have some mistakes in your markup, like the `<title>` should be inside `<head>` tag( for heading use `<h1>` upto `<h7>` tags ). Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
 <title>"My Page"</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>hello jQuery</h1>
 <div id="slider"></div>

<!-- load scripts -->

 <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui.js">
 </script>
 <script src="js/jqueryTutorial.js">
 </script>

  </body>   

 </html>
```

And your javascript will simply be:

```
$('#slider').slider();
```

if that doesn't works try:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
 $('#slider').slider();
}
```

Because if you include them at beginning, whole HTML document will not be completely loaded at the time the scripts get executed, so the script won't be able to find elements.

**And** I don't think `.slider()` gives you what you want. I suggest you learn more first. Try [www.codecademy.com](http://codecademy.com)

Comment: @dexterous_stranger I wonder from where you are learning web development

Comment: I have even copied the code from jquery website. it's still not working. You can check my revised question now... check at the below.